# SQL Query to Join Multiple Tables in Sandbox

Tags: mysql, sql, join, create-table

I'm writing a query to combine data from multiple tables within a sandbox environment. I'm getting a SQL 1100 error message on first `CREATE TABLE` after the `DROP`.

Error message:

> SQL Error [1100] [HY000]: ERROR:  'CREATE TABLE
> Sandbox..CF_Promocodeused AS ( SELECT DISTINCT visitid, visitdate,
> post_evar23, post_evar16, post_evar17, post_evar10 FROM
> IDM..HITDATAHISTORY WHERE brandcode = ‘FDM’ AND post_evar23 IS NOT
> NULL )' error
> ^ found "‘" (at char 179) Illegal initial character in identifier

I welcome any ideas from the community. Thank you in advance.

Code used:

```
DROP TABLE Sandbox..CF_Promocodeused IF EXISTS;
CREATE TABLE Sandbox..CF_Promocodeused AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT visitid, visitdate, post_evar23, post_evar16, post_evar17, post_evar10
FROM IDM..HITDATAHISTORY
WHERE brandcode = ‘FDM’
AND post_evar23 IS NOT NULL
)
;

DROP TABLE Sandbox..CF_Promocodeused1 IF EXISTS;
CREATE TABLE Sandbox..CF_Promocodeused1 AS (
SELECT DISTINCT post_evar23, visitdate, post_evar16, post_evar17, post_evar10, COUNT(DISTINCT visitid) AS visits, calendardate, subtotalamount
FROM IDM..Sandbox..CF_Promocodeused AS h
INNER JOIN IDM..ORDERFACT AS o ON h.ordernumber = o.ordernumber
INNER JOIN IDM..DATEDIM AS d ON d.fiscalmonthname = h.fiscalmonthname
WHERE calendardate BETWEEN '01/27/2021 00:00:00’ AND 02/23/2021 23:59:59'
AND subtotalamount >= '200.00'
```

Comment: Hi, please tag your question with the DBMS you are using and update your question with the full text of the error message

Comment: Thanks. However, DBeaver is not a DBMS, its a developer tool. A DBMS is something like Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, Postgres, etc

Comment: Possibly the wrong types of quote mark round FDM. They look like ticks ’ rather than single quotes '

Comment: Updated tags.  Pretty sure this is MySQL and not MSSQL.